# How to continue the game from the score saved in firebase database? Android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So i have created a quizz game and i have dificulty to continue the score from what is saved in database. I start game activity and get to 30 points for example if i exit activity and go to profile where i find the updated score and come back it resets my score to 0 both in game and database.
I need to be able to continue from last saved score. Where have i gone wrong?
p.s. It's my first time asking a question here.
Here is the game code:

```
package com.sandu.quizz4games;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Random;


public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {



    AdView adView;
    Button ans1_btn, ans2_btn, ans3_btn, ans4_btn, back_btn;
    TextView  question, score;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    String userId;

    private Questions mQuestions = new Questions();
    Random r;
    private String mAnswer;
    private int mQuestionsLength = mQuestions.mQuestions.length;

    int uScore;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        //Initiate
               r = new Random();
          adView = findViewById(R.id.add);
        ans1_btn = findViewById(R.id.ans1_btn);
        ans2_btn = findViewById(R.id.ans2_btn);
        ans3_btn = findViewById(R.id.ans3_btn);
        ans4_btn = findViewById(R.id.ans4_btn);

        back_btn = findViewById(R.id.back_btn);

        question = findViewById(R.id.question);
        score    = findViewById(R.id.score);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
        final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        assert user != null;
        userId = user.getUid();





        myRef.child("users").child(userId).child("eScore").setValue(uScore);


        //...//



        // update question randomizer
          updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
         //...//

        //Button Functions

        ans1_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ans1_btn.getText() == mAnswer){
                    uScore+=10;
                    Toast.makeText(Game.this,"Corect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    score.setText("Score: "+ String.valueOf(uScore));
                    myRef.child("users").child(userId).child("eScore").setValue(uScore);
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));

                }else
                    gameOver();


            }
        });

        ans2_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ans2_btn.getText() == mAnswer){
                    Toast.makeText(Game.this,"Corect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    uScore+=10;
                    score.setText("Score: "+ String.valueOf(uScore));
                    myRef.child("users").child(userId).child("eScore").setValue(uScore);
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));

                }else
                    gameOver();


            }

        });
        ans3_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ans3_btn.getText() == mAnswer){
                    Toast.makeText(Game.this,"Corect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    uScore+=10;
                    score.setText("Score: "+ String.valueOf(uScore));
                    myRef.child("users").child(userId).child("eScore").setValue(uScore);
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));

            }else
                gameOver();


            }
        });
        ans4_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ans4_btn.getText() == mAnswer){
                    Toast.makeText(Game.this,"Corect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    uScore+=10;
                    score.setText("Score: "+ String.valueOf(uScore));
                    myRef.child("users").child(userId).child("eScore").setValue(uScore);
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));

                }else
                    gameOver();


            }
        });

        back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Game.this,Home.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });



        //...//



        // Full Screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        //.....//
        // AdMob add - Banner
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        //...//


    }

    // Update Question Function
        private void updateQuestion(int num){

        question.setText(mQuestions.getQuestions(num));
        ans1_btn.setText(mQuestions.getChoice1(num));
        ans2_btn.setText(mQuestions.getChoice2(num));
        ans3_btn.setText(mQuestions.getChoice3(num));
        ans4_btn.setText(mQuestions.getChoice4(num));


        mAnswer = mQuestions.getCorrectAnswer(num);

        }

    //...//


    //Other Functions
        private void gameOver(){
            uScore -=5;
            Toast.makeText(Game.this,"Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (uScore < 0){
            uScore = 0;
            score.setText("0");
        }
            score.setText("Score: "+ String.valueOf(uScore));
            myRef.child("users").child(userId).child("eScore").setValue(uScore);
           updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
        }

    //...//





        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `myRef.child("users").child(userId).child("eScore")` exists in your database lets first read its score from the database and save it to `uScore` variable.

Comment: I have tried that using event listener and on change i have put uScore=datasnapshot.child("users").child(userId).child(eScore).getValue(Integer.class);  and it did not work.

Comment: @AndreiSandu Why do you say it didn't work? Please post another question with that.

Comment: I apologize it was a good suggestion and i have tried it but just now i found out that i had a line of code that was canceling my attempt. Thank you guys!!!